# How do I get a count of values based on custom bucket-ranges I create for a select column in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a column in my dataset by name 'production_output' whose values are integers in the range of 2.300000e+01 to 1.110055e+08.

I want to arbitrarily split the values in this column into different buckets based on say, percentile ranges like say [0, 25, 50, 75, 100] and get count of the length of each of theses buckets.

How do I do this using python data-science packages?

Comment: Your asking how to compute a histogram.

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

Comment: @kbrose, you are correct. What I'm essentially asking is the background  computations done for histogram. And I'm so asking, because I don't see a way to pass parameters to histogram function to get things or am I missing something here?

Comment: To that guy who down-voted this question without a reason: Why down-voting this question without giving any reason? What a way to help your community members? If you can't help, at least get out of the way from mothers answering this question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your question does not show much research. I’m not saying you *didn’t* research, but there’s no evidence in your question. Maybe it would have been improved by you saying what you tried, what you googled already, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.histogram`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Use `numpy.percentile` to get the bin edges you desire.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html